# jQuery - Highlight Divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I have a routine written using jQuery that i want to highlight divs if their property matches that of the button...

```
$links = $('.property');
$links.click(function(e) {
    //Get our variables, simply $(this) and the colour
    var $this = $(this),
        color = $this.data('col');

    //Toggle the active class on this link
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    //Remove .main on all .test's
    $(".slayout").removeClass("main");
    $(".product").addClass("trans");
    $(".product").removeClass("main");

    //Map the active link's data-col with a dot attributes to an array
    //Join it up to make a selector
    var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
        return "."+$(this).data('col');
    }).get().join('');

    //Add the class back on to matches
    $(selector).addClass('main');

    //Finally, prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/os40xLof/

For some reason it's not working how i want.  If I click on 'Hot' then I expect the two items with 'Hot' in them to be highlighted and the rest to be dimmed.

But for some reason everything is starting off dimmed, where am I going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is wrong, add more specificity to `.slayout` rule:

```
.main { opacity:1; }
.main.slayout { opacity:0.3; }
```

Comment: That changes things slightly but the wrong things are being highlighted

Comment: @fightstarr20 When you click in `HOT`, it gets `.active`, then if you click in `DARK`, both get `.active` and `Dark - Hot` gets highlighted. You need to click again in `HOT` or `DARK` to disable it. That's not what you want?

Comment: Almost, it is meant to have multiple clicks, so I can click hot and cold at the same time

Comment: @fightstarr20 what do you mean multiple *clicks*? Can you update the question properly, explaining what should happen when you click *" hot and cold at the same time"* ??